# Removing duplicate from string challenge

Tags: python, string

i have one problem i want to remove the duplicates from string for example if i have uppercase letter and second letter is lowercase of same type (C,c) i want to remove the lowercase for example look the how is my output and how it should look like downwards in code , but i have idea when result finishes i want to iterate through each element and check if its for example letter of same type but i coudn't implement it.

```
def camel_case(string):
    result = ''
    new_string = string.capitalize()
    for i in range(len(new_string)):
        if new_string[i] == " ":
            result += new_string[i+1].upper()
        else:  
            result += new_string[i]
    return result 
print(camel_case("camel case method")) # my output: CamelCcaseMmethod , output for question should look like:CamelCaseMethod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your function a bit.

```
def camel_case(string):
    t = False
    result = ''
    new_string = string.capitalize()
    for i in new_string:
        if i == " ":
            t = True
        else:
            if t:
                result += i.upper()
            else: 
                result+= i
            t = False
    return result 
print(camel_case("camel case method"))
```

You can use this one also

```
def camel_case(string):
    return string.title().replace(' ','') 
print(camel_case("camel case method"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution for this callenge does not works effective:

Try this instead:

```
from re import sub

def camel_case(s):
    s = sub(r"(_|-)+", " ", s).title().replace(" ", "")
    return ''.join([s[0].lower(), s[1:]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be;

```
s.title().replace(" ","")
```